# Adding HSRP VLAN to existing config before connecting interfaces

Tags: cisco, hsrp

Apologies I am new to Cisco and have inherited two Cisco 9300's with HSRP.

There are four existing VLAN's and when setup the switches were not in production. An example config of VLAN1 is below:

```
(SWITCH1) interface Vlan1
 description ***Default Vlan 1***
 ip address 10.65.6.2 255.255.255.0
 standby 1 ip 10.65.6.1
 standby 1 timers msec 200 msec 600
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt delay reload 60
!

(SWITCH2) interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.65.6.3 255.255.255.0
 standby 1 ip 10.65.6.1
 standby 1 timers msec 200 msec 600
 standby 1 preempt delay reload 60
 standby 1 track 1 decrement 20
!
```

I would like to add a fifth, and preferably do it ahead of when I have to go there and connect the assets (the switches are in a coloco in another country).

- Can I add the next HSRP VLAN even though there are no assets for that VLAN connected?
- Should I add the configuration to the ACTIVE switch first then the second?

Obviously what I am trying to do here is to not trigger any flapping whilst adding the next HSRP VLAN.

Any advice / recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HSRP is an instance per vlan, adding a new vlan with HSRP config won't cause any issues (as long as the new vlan isn't looped to the existing vlans).  If you want to be very sure about the stability of your HSRP, use a unique group id and authentication key per vlan.

Also for business network questions, check out https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/.